# How to reset python interpreters in PyDev?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I saved two python interpreters in PyDev a year ago or so. Since then I've uninstalled those interpreters from my system (they were python 2.7) and installed a new one python 3.6.

Every time I restarts eclipse, PyDev loads my old interpreters. Then I have to go into the settings, remove then, apply and save, then add the new interpreter. Adding a new interpreter takes around 10 minutes because it needs to update the PYTHONPATH and load all modules. During this 10 minutes, I'm unable to use Eclipse, can't do any code editing whatsoever. Even if I save the new interpreter, next time I restart Eclipse, the same thing happens.

I tried uninstalling Eclipse, uninstalling PyDev, or delete my Eclipse workspace, or PyDev folder in eclipse workspace, it has no effect. Where does PyDev store the interpreter information?? I read that it should store it in the Eclipse workspace, but this cannot be the case, since even if I delete my Eclipse workspace, it loads the old interpreter configuration.

Answer (score 0):

PyDev saves the configuration of the interpreter configuration in the wokspace preferences, now, if you're using Oomph, it has an option to persist those for the user and when a new workspace is created it'll restore those preferences for you.

So, what I think is happening is that you recorded those preferences with Oomph and whenever you change them in PyDev Oomph restores it.

There was a similar report in the PyDev tracker some time ago: https://www.brainwy.com/tracker/PyDev/671.

To fix this you should remove the recorded preference from Oomph (see: https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2014/november/article2.php).