# Python interpreters frequently reset on restarting eclipse

Tags: python, python-3.x, eclipse, pydev, oomph

I have recently changed the username on my MacBook and deleted the previous installation of miniconda to install new anaconda. Moving forward, I removed previous definition for python interpreter based on miniconda `(py36)` from `Eclipse > Preferences > PyDev > Python Interpreter`, to add a new anaconda based python interpreter. These changes are working fine for the current session, or a quick restart of eclipse, however, if I reopen eclipse after a day or so, the interpreter settings are being switched back to the old settings. And I need to remove the old interpreter and add new interpreter all over again. The following is the error I receive with eclipse restart.

Error: An internal error occurred during: "List dependencies for: py36 (/Users/Viswanath/miniconda3/bin/python)". java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/Users/Viswanath/miniconda3/bin/python": error=2, No such file or directory

[image: Error Dialog]

Similar question has been asked in the past [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52841931/110451). As mentioned in the answer to that question and here, I also believe that the root cause could be preference recording by a plugin such as Oomph. However, the [documentation page for Oomph](https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2014/november/article2.php) doesn't help with steps to remove the preference recording or presets. As shown in the following images, I unchecked the options from `Eclipse > Preferences > Oomph > Setup Tasks > Preference Recorder & Preference Synchronizer`. Neither of these helped. Any help with directions to remove the recorded preference or presets from Oomph are appreciated.

[image]

[image]
**Additional Details:**

```
Python Version: 3.7.8
Eclipse Version: 2020-09 (4.17.0)
PyDev Version: 8.0.1
Device: MacBook Pro
OS: macOS Big Sur 11.0.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what did the trick was to delete the recorded preferences from Navigate -> Open Setup -> User -> Group named "User Pereferences".

Answer (score 1):

The usual culprit here is that you have some plugin such as Oomph which is recording the preferences (and thus, it saves your configuration to the Python interpreter and when you restart Eclipse it restores those configurations, thus restoring the old interpreter config).

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52841931/110451

Comment: Thank you! I think you are right about Oomph, however, the I couldn't remove the preference recording from Oomph. Edited the original post with further details.

Comment: After removing the preferences synchronization, did you manually redo the interpreter configuration? After that in theory after a restart the settings should not be overridden.